# How do I get my mysql statement to return something when one of the table it can pull from might be empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code:

```
SELECT U.Name AS name, U.ID AS ID, U.student AS stud, IF(U.activeImage IS NOT NULL,I.image,U.activeImage) AS img 
FROM CLOCKED_IN C, USERS U, IMAGES I 
WHERE C.userID=U.userID 
ORDER BY U.student DESC
```

Currently even if I have a user in clocked in and users, this will return an empty set, I assume because there are no rows saved in images. How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is what you need, its a fundamental part of SQL and one you'd need to understand if you want to master the topic.

The FROM part is probably something like (note I've using T-SQL not mySQL):

```
FROM         USER U LEFT OUTER JOIN
             IMAGES I ON U.userID = I.userID LEFT OUTER JOIN
             CLOCKED_IN C ON C.userID = U.userID
```